# multi-label classfication project: how to improve bad performance

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

**Contextualization**
I am building a model that identifes three categories in a given image.
There are three categories:

- *Gender:* male/female
- *Type clotes:* Blazers,Blazers&Jacket,Blouses,Cardigan,Coats,Coats&Jackets,Culottes,Dresses,Jeans,Jumper,Jumpsuits&Dungarees,Knitwear&Sweatshirts,Leggings&CigaretteTrousers,Maternity,Polo,Pololong,Shirts,Shorts,Skirts,Suits,Swimwear,Swimwear & Beachwear,T-shirts,T-shirts & Tops,Trousers,Tunics.
- *Color clothes:* beige,black,blue,brown,green,grey,orange,pink,red,white,yellow.

In other words every image should have these 3 categories ( one value per category).

**Data**
My database for **training my model** is composed of **1812** images and an excel file containing the values of the three categories for each image ( and its url).
Here are some information about my database:

- number of males: 759
- number of females: 1055
- I also have the number of times each attribute ( from each category) is appearing in my database  ( I can't list all of them, but if it's something usefull for interpretation I can send you that information)
- most appearing triplet is (Male,Jeans,blue):  66 times

**What I have done**
It seemed pretty clear that I am in a multi-label classification context.
**1. Clean & preprocess my data**
I created **(X,Y)** data where **X** is is of shape **(1814,204,204,3)** and **Y** is of shape **(1814,39)** '' 39 corresponds to the dummy variable : category 1 has 2 attributes, category 2 has 26 attribute , category 3 has 11 attributes: so total makes 39 ''.
**2. Building my neural neural network**
the different parameters of my model are :

- epochs = 100
- lrate = 0.001
- decay = lrate/epochs
- sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
- loss=binary_crossentropy
- optimizer=sgd
- metrics=accuracy

The structure of my trained network is as follows:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 204, 204, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 204, 204, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 204, 204, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 102, 102, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 332928)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 512)               170459648 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 39)                20007     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 39)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 170,489,799
Trainable params: 170,489,799
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Questions**

1. I don't think my metric ='accuracy' is  a good choice: it doesn't reflect the reality of what happens. For example, I executed an evaluation test on my training data and got 0.95 ( 95% of all bins are well classified), but that doesn't mean the model is doing well because in every output: there should be 3 ones out of the 39 components and all the remaining are zeros.. so there is a high probability to have a lot of zeros and thus even in the worse case the 39 values are predicted to be 0 ( nothing is detected) than we have 36/39 accuracy: which doesn't reflect the real issue? ( That's what I got as a result, for a given X, i got many Values near to zeros , so when I use a threshold (0.5) it makes everything equal to zero: I tried to implement a threshold based on statistical approach using mathiew correlation coefficient: but still doesn't add anything usefull) .. So , what do you think is a good metric for a multi-label classification problem with many (39) labels output?
2. Do you think that the bad performance of my model comes from the fact that I don't have many images? ( images per label ) ?
3. Do you think my model has bad performance because the structure of Neural network is not good? I tried to used a pretrained model where I fix first layers since state of the art says that these layers are responsible for detecting edges, and I trained only next layers: In that case I have also bad results (calcaluated through the 'accuracy' metric?
4. To sum up , i Know that maybe there is not a universal solution to my issues, but at least I want to know what may cause these kind of issues and how to remedy them? So any help especially from people who worked on multi-label classifications with many labels at the output, is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many threads and webpages about "what to try next" and "how to make the neural network work" but I would start with

1) Balancing the data so that every label appears equally. If most of your data set is composed of "male, blue jeans" then this will contribute to the loss function the most, and so the optimizer will focus on this case, but not, say, the "female, fedora" case, of which you may have one sample. So just duplicate the data so all the sampled appear equally. You can also do a weighted cost which is slightly more involved.

2) Continuing from above, start on a small balanced data set and see if you can overfit it (pick one data point from each class). This will give you a good starting point and iron out bugs. From that, start adding more and more data and monitor the loss function.

3) For metrics, compute accuracy, precision, and recall per class (gender, type, color). You can also compute the confusion matrix which is my personal favorite if you don't have many classes. There is a nice demo of a confusion matrix (and other metrics) on this excellent page (Demo: Looking inside neural nets)
https://ml4a.github.io/ml4a/looking_inside_neural_nets/

Good luck.